# T-Sql count string sequences over multiple rows

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

How can I find subsets of data over multiple rows in sql?

I want to count the number of occurrences of a string (or number) before another string is found and then count the number of times this string occurs before another one is found.
All these strings can be in random order.

This is what I want to achieve:

I have one table with one column (`columnx`) with data like this:

```
A
A
B
C
A
B
B
```

The result I want from the query should be like this:

```
2 A
1 B
1 C
1 A
2 B
```

Is this even possible in sql or would it be easier just to write a little C# app to do this?

Comment: There must be a column (or a set of columns) that determines the sequence. Rows in a table are unordered by default.

Comment: You *must* have another column (or columns) that can be used to determine the correct order of your values. SQL *never* ***guarantees*** the order data is processed, stored or displayed, without some other data to *explicitly* determine that order. For example : `SELECT columnx FROM yourTable ORDER BY sort_order`. Do you have a column like `sort_order` by which you can order the data? *[Also, what version of SQL Server/SyBase/etc are you using?]*

Comment: I can add an auto increment column or a date column for ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can do it with a single select.
You can use AdventureWorks cursor:

```
create table my_Strings
(
my_string varchar(50)
)


insert into my_strings values('A'),('A'),('B'),('C'),('A'),('B'),('B') -- this method will only work on SQL Server 2008

--select my_String from my_strings 

declare @temp_result table(
string varchar(50),
nr int)

declare @myString varchar(50)
declare @myLastString varchar(50)
declare @nr int

set @myLastString='A' --set this with the value of your FIRST string  on the table
set @nr=0

DECLARE string_cursor CURSOR
FOR 
SELECT my_string as aux_column FROM my_strings  

OPEN string_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM string_cursor into @myString
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    if (@myString = @myLastString) begin
        set @nr=@nr+1
        set @myLastString=@myString
    end else begin
        insert into @temp_result values (@myLastString, @nr)
        set @myLastString=@myString
        set @nr=1
    end
    FETCH NEXT FROM string_cursor into @myString
END
insert into @temp_result values (@myLastString, @nr)
CLOSE string_cursor;
DEALLOCATE string_cursor;

select * from @temp_result
```

Result:

```
A   2
B   1
C   1
A   1
B   2
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, I'm going to try this on the real data as soon as I can.

Answer (score 3):

Since, as per your comment, you can add a column that will unambiguously define the order in which the `columnx` values go, you can try the following query (provided the SQL product you are using supports CTEs and ranking functions):

```
WITH marked AS (
  SELECT
    columnx,
    sortcolumn,
    grp = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (                     ORDER BY sortcolumn)
        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY columnx ORDER BY sortcolumn)
  FROM data
)
SELECT
  columnx,
  COUNT(*)
FROM marked
GROUP BY
  columnx,
  grp
ORDER BY
  MIN(sortcolumn)
;
```

You can see the method in work [on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b7d0/3).

If `sortcolumn` is an auto-increment integer column that is guaranteed to have no gaps, you can replace the first `ROW_NUMBER()` expression with just `sortcolumn`. But, I guess, that cannot be guaranteed in general. Besides, you might indeed want to sort on a timestamp instead of an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
;with sample as (
    select 'A' as columnx
    union all
    select 'A'
    union all
    select 'B'
    union all
    select 'C'
    union all
    select 'A'
    union all
    select 'B'
    union all
    select 'B'
), data 
as (
select columnx,
  Row_Number() over(order by (select 0)) id 
  from  sample
  ) , CTE as (

        select * , 
  Row_Number() over(order by (select 0)) rno from data

  ) , result as (

     SELECT  d.*
                , ( SELECT  MAX(ID)
                    FROM    CTE c
                    WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CTE
                                        WHERE rno = c.rno-1 and columnx = c.columnx)
                            AND c.ID <= d.ID) AS g
        FROM    data d
  )



SELECT columnx,
       COUNT(1) cnt
FROM   result
GROUP  BY columnx,
          g
```

Result :

```
columnx cnt
A         2
B         1
C         1
A         1
B         2
```

Comment: This query seems to work well too, as expected all these queries are taking forever if you have almost 2 million rows :)